# jquery sortable is conflict by the introduction of a conditional statement in a second function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

In the following script, the conditional statements seem to stop the HTML ul's from being sortable.

```
    <script>

 $(function makeSort() {
    $( ".scramble" ).sortable();

    $( ".scramble" ).disableSelection();

   });

const answer = {
                Q1: "I can't play piano",
                Q2: "The moon is a green balloon"                    
                };
const QNo = 2;               
function checkOrd() {

        $('#quiz').find('ul').each(function() {
        let sentenceId = $(this).attr('id');
        sentence = $.map($('#' + sentenceId + ' li'), function(element) {return $(element).text()}).join(' ');
        alert(sentence + " " + answer[sentenceId])

        //if (sentence == answer[sentenceId]) {
        //alert(OK!)
        //} else{
        //alert(nope!)
        //}

        });

    };

</script>
```

the HTML is:

```
    <div id = "quiz">
<ul class= "scramble" id = "Q1">
<li>I</li>
<li>piano</li>
<li>can't</li>
<li>play</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>


<ul class="scramble" id = "Q2" >
<li>moon</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>balloon</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>The</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>

</div>
```

The script, as it is, allows the ul#scramble to be sortable. However if the conditional is uncommented nothing works i.e. not sortable and no response to the button click. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Your commented alert arguments are missing quotation marks. E.g `alert(nope!)` should be `alert("nope!")`.

Comment: What if the arguments are strings 'OK!' and 'nope!'

Comment: Wow! And I've been staring at that for over an hour!! Thank you

Comment: @user1478335 Are you using console to debug? This error would've been pretty evident :)

Comment: No. I have never used that. Will give it a try. Thank you for the pointer!